# Is it possible to replace HTML entities in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

The XML I have has some HTML entities in the "Text" node

```
<b/> --> &amp;lt;/b&gt;&amp;
<br/> --> &amp;lt;/b&gt;&amp;
<p/> --> &amp;lt;/p&gt;&amp;
```

I want to replace the

`&amp;lt;/b&gt;&amp;` with nothing 
`&amp;lt;/b&gt;&amp;` with linefeed & carriage return
`&amp;lt;/p&gt;&amp;` with space

My requirement is to use Text nodes in the output and not CDATA

Can I achieve this replacement using XSLT 1.0?

My input xml node looks like this

`<P SI="description">&amp;lt;/b&gt;&amp;lt;br&gt;&amp;lt;/br&gt;01 - Ths is a test node&amp;lt;br&gt;&amp;lt;/br&gt;&amp;lt;br&gt;&amp;lt;/br&gt;&amp;lt;br&gt;&amp;lt;/br&gt;&amp;lt;br&gt;&amp;lt;/br&gt;Press F2 dfafe</P>`

I need after the transformation,

```
<P SI="description">

01 - Ths is a test node








Press F2 dfafe</P>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform multiple replace operations. I suggest you download the template from [here](http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/index.html) (bottom of the page) and call it from your stylesheet.